# Cannot build project when updated Typescript to latest version. (exited with code 1)

Tags: typescript

HI I am in the process of updating typescript version on our project. we are currently using the 0.9.1.1 version of typescript. I have verified one by one that all TS files are compiled correctly as well as the definition types (d.ts) files.

and now I am encountering an error when building the project. we are using MVC 4.

the error says: *the command "[project path]" exited with code 1.*

We are using VS2012 and I already modify the csproj file to compile following this instructions from this site: http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

Comment: So something like : `the command "c:\myproject\solution.sln" exited with code 1.`?

Comment: yes. I checked all my ts files if there is still error. yet still encountering the error.

Comment: can you look at the output window OR error list window, anything in there?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a vague message within Visual Studio I fire up `tsc` via the command line - where I can see the full output. This often tells me something that for some reason went missing via the Visual Studio extension.

For example, if I am compiling `app.ts` with a bunch of references to other files and I'm combining the output, I'll manually run the command...

```
tsc --out final.js app.ts
```